# QZ dot matrix printing on EPSON LQ-50 raw print issue

Tags: html, printing, dot-matrix, qz-tray

I am using EPSON LQ-50 Dot matrix printer to print a receipt the height is 10cm and width is 15 cm ,

I have tried 2 ways i.e HTML Print and other is RAW print but in both the cases the the printer behavior is different ,

Case 1: (HTML) In qz settings the HTML printing comes under pixel printing so I can select the units as I needed So it print comes as I wanted. Now when I cut the receipt from cuttings and gives the next print using same HTML it reverse back the paper from start the start and prints it perfectly fine. So over all the the print with html works perfect all the time when I print.

Case 2: (RAW) I have created the Raw data for print as as the html format looks and when I print the the same the printer prints all the given data and stop exactly at the point where data ends. So some printed data remains inside if I cut the paper I left some printed data inside.
  I solved the same using next line code which complete printing and leave some space but this is not the option because when next print given printer doesnot adjust the paper from start it starts printing from where it is . but html printing works perfect.

Cannot find the printer setting or qz Config to adjust the print from the start of paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i understood your problem, had faced the same. It can be solved by changing one of your Printing preferences option. Follow the below steps

Start-> Control Panel->View devices and printers(under Hardware and Sound),
right click on your specific printer icons; select Printing preferences. Click on Paper/Quality and select "Tractor" option from the Paper-Source drop down and restart your printer then try.
Hope this will do. All the best !!